# Azure blob index tags returning deleted blobs

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage, azure-storage

I am using azure find blobs by tags api https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/find-blobs-by-tags in java, but it also returns blobs which are not there in the container. When i try to get blobs returned by the find blobs by tags api, it gives me 404 blob does not exist.
If it helps, soft delete is disabled on my account and i delete blobs via delete blob api in batch.

[image]

Comment: Please edit to show specific details, including relevant code, expected vs actual output, contents of the container you're querying, errors, etc.

Comment: Note: even with your edits, this is still off-topic, as you still haven't provided any detail. You have to show your work, so people can help figure out what you might have done wrong. Your screenshot doesn't really help.

Comment: This is the problem which we are facing on azure portal UI also, there is no code involved as of now. We tried searching blobs via index tags "Add Filter" button on azure portal UI and it returns blobs which does not exist as visible in screenshot.
When we try to see the details of blobs returned by index tags filter, it says specified blobs does not exist.
Need help to understand why index tags filter on azure blob portal UI returns stale/garbage blobs

Comment: Soft delete is disabled before deleting blobs or after deleting blobs?

Comment: Soft delete is disabled before deleting blobs and currently still disabled.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK,
I can see that you have given that deleted blob snapshots also exists in the Azure Blob Storage container as shown in your image.

This is because as given in this [MS Doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/soft-delete-blob-manage#view-deleted-snapshots)

> If a soft-deleted blob has snapshots, the deleted snapshots can also be displayed in the Azure portal.

Blobs are invisible by default if soft-deletion is happened and shows the status as Deleted state but that soft-deleted blobs will contains the snapshots are not automatically deleted.